# How can i list all handles used by a process in c++ (windows)?

Tags: c++, windows

From my research I found how  to do it with process explorer, or also the handle.exe of sysinternals. but i can't find how to do in c++.

I can list all the process running using the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot of the TlHelp32.h, so i thought iterating through every process entry i could get a list of its handles.
I found **EnumProcessModules** but I want only handles not modules. **NtQuerySystemInformation** function might do it apparently but i just don't know how?

Comment: One option is to look at the source code for [YAPM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yaprocmon/files/YAPM-beta/YAPM-2.4.2/) (*Yet Another Process Monitor*).

Comment: That's not possible.  Mark Russinovich's secret is dynamically installing a device driver that can poke around in internal kernel tables.  Well, it is possible if you're Mark.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.